# Entity Framework: how do I discard changes relations?

Tags: entity-framework, dbcontext

I have a problem when I delete one entity that is relation with itself.

```
public class example
{
    [Key]
    public int exampleid { get; set; }
    public string example { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("Example")]
    public int? RelationID { get; set; }
    public virtual Example Example { get; set; }
}
```

If I use...

```
 Example E1 = ctx.find(Id);// E1 has a relation with other object Example.
 ctx.Entry(E1).State = EntityState.Delete; 
 var E2 = ctx.Examples.Find(E1.RelationID);
 ctx.entry(E2).state = state.Modified;
 ctx.savechanges(); // remove both entities.
```

Is there any way to do this without removing the other entity?

Thanks..; P

Comment: RelationID = null, then set deleted

Comment: yes, when i change the state to delete the Property RelationID is null, i want avoid this. i don't see my error. the object has other similar properties and don't work the same way.

Answer (score 0):

it's solved. It was my mistake, forgot to delete one line in to my code that change de state of the reference Object to deleted. The Class correctly defined.